# Double Encoding of HTML Entities in XML using VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to create an XML file using VB.NET for a system that accepts XML information for publication on their website. Even though special characters like © & ® are acceptable in the XML, they really should be encoded to `&copy;` and `&reg;`.

The problem that I am having is when I insert `&copy;` into the XML, it results in a double-encoding of `&amp;copy;` in the XML, if I insert ©, then © is inserted unencoded.

I created a bare-bones example that I have replicated the problem with below, it has the same XML structure as what I need. I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to convert entities.

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Private Sub webXML()

    Dim oXml As New XmlDocument

    oXml.LoadXml("<webTable xmlns=""http://www.test.com/test1"" xmlns:n1=""http://www.test.com/test2"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.test.com/test3"" xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.test.com/test4""></webTable>")

    ''Add Namespace
    Dim NS As New Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(oXml.NameTable)
    NS.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.test.com/test1")
    NS.AddNamespace("n1", "http://www.test.com/test2")
    NS.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.test.com/test3")

    ''Create XML declaration 
    Dim xmldecl As XmlDeclaration
    xmldecl = oXml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", Nothing)
    xmldecl.Encoding = "UTF-8"

    ''Add node to document 
    Dim root As XmlElement = oXml.DocumentElement
    oXml.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root)

    ''info
    Dim info As XmlNode = oXml.CreateNode("element", "info", "http://www.test.com/test1")

    ''data1
    Dim data1 As XmlNode = oXml.CreateNode("element", "data1", "http://www.test.com/test1")
    Dim data1Value As String = HtmlEntity.Entitize(Trim("Company Name 1 ©"), True)
    Dim data1Text As XmlText = oXml.CreateTextNode(data1Value)
    data1.AppendChild(data1Text)
    info.AppendChild(data1)
    Console.WriteLine("Data1 value: " + data1Value)
    Console.WriteLine("Data1 text node value: " + data1Text.Value)
    Console.WriteLine("Data1 node text value: " + data1.InnerText)
    Console.WriteLine("Data1 node XML value: " + data1.InnerXml)

    ''data2
    Dim data2 As XmlNode = oXml.CreateNode("element", "data2", "http://www.test.com/test1")
    Dim data2Value As String = Trim(HtmlEntity.Entitize("Company Name 2 ®", False))
    data2.InnerText = data2Value
    info.AppendChild(data2)
    Console.WriteLine("Data2 value: " + data2Value)
    Console.WriteLine("Data2 node text value: " + data2.InnerText)
    Console.WriteLine("Data2 node XML value: " + data2.InnerXml)

    ''data3
    Dim data3 As XmlNode = oXml.CreateNode("element", "data3", "http://www.test.com/test1")
    Dim data3value As String = Trim(HtmlEntity.Entitize("Company Name 3 ®", False))
    data3.InnerXml = data3value
    info.AppendChild(data3)
    Console.WriteLine("Data3 value: " + data3value)
    Console.WriteLine("Data3 node text value: " + data3.InnerText)
    Console.WriteLine("Data3 node XML value: " + data3.InnerXml)

    ''Add info to Root
    root.AppendChild(info)

    oXml.Save(Console.Out)
    oXml.Save("C:\Users\Me\Dropbox\Junk\textXML.xml")

End Sub
```

The output I get is:

```
Data1 value: Company Name 1 &copy;
Data1 text node value: Company Name 1 &copy;
Data1 node text value: Company Name 1 &copy;
Data1 node XML value: Company Name 1 &amp;copy;
Data2 value: Company Name 2 &#174;
Data2 node text value: Company Name 2 &#174;
Data2 node XML value: Company Name 2 &amp;#174;
Data3 value: Company Name 3 &#174;
Data3 node text value: Company Name 3 ®
Data3 node XML value: Company Name 3 ®
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<webTable xmlns="http://www.test.com/test1" xmlns:n1="http://www.test.com/test2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.test.com/test3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/test4">
  <info>
    <data1>Company Name 1 &amp;copy;</data1>
    <data2>Company Name 2 &amp;#174;</data2>
    <data3>Company Name 3 ®</data3>
  </info>
</webTable>
```

As you can see I have tries several different ways and I still can't get the entities encoded right.

Please note that `oXml.Save(Console.Out)` shows `Windows-1252` encoding but my output file is identical except it shows it properly as `UTF-8`.

I'm using VS 2012 Express.

Any idea what I can do to encode the HTML entities properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: place your html in CDATA blocks.  `<data1><![CDATA[Company name 1 &copy; 2014]]></data1>`  -  [CDATA on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Comment: The end system that I post to would accept this no problem, however the "Viewer" that we use to check and send the XML chokes on CDATA. It also chokes on loading unescaped entities. Sorry for not posting that info earlier.

Comment: XML viewers/validators are pretty simple.  Update yours or write a new one?  It sounds as if your viewer and the consumer service do not talk the same language (so to speak).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I contacted the developers of the "viewer" and they will make an update to allow importing of CDATA.